How to dynamically change the color of an element inside an SVG file with JavaScript?
I'm experimenting with HTML, CSS and SVG files. I have an elaborate illustration saved as an SVG file. Inside this file, I have two elements with a unique ID: COLOR1 and COLOR2. As default they have a fill in Red (COLOR1) and Yellow (COLOR2).
I loaded the SVG file into the HTML page using the <object> method. The SVG is too complicated to embed it inline and the page, after the experiment, can have more than only one SVG file of the same kind.
    <object id="Soldier" type="image/svg+xml" data="ProvaSVG.svg" width="400" height="400">
    <param name="src" value="ProvaSVG.svg">
    </object>

I want to change, at page load, the colors of these two elements, according to different values supplied by a database. For example COLOR1 to Green and COLOR2 to Blue.
This is what I did:
Soldier.COLOR1.fill='Green';
Soldier.COLOR2.fill='Blue';

How I correctly address the elements to change their fill values? I want to use plain JavaScript, not jQuery or other dependencies.

AFAIK you will not be able to edit anything about an SVG if it's embedded using object or img. Solider.shadowRoot is null

But I read that loading SVG with  I will be able to edit SVG elements.

Where did you read this?

I don't have the links anymore but in at least a couple of sites. And Roko seems to solve it, though I didn't try yet, bercause I have to set a localhost before.

You can load your externaL SVG file with my 7 line modern native JavaScript Web Component <load-file>
That will inline it into your document, making all CSS possible.
With option to add (replaceWith) it to global DOM or (default) into shadowDOM.
Full docs: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd


customElements.define("load-file", class extends HTMLElement {
  async connectedCallback(
    src = this.getAttribute("src"),
    shadowRoot = this.shadowRoot || this.attachShadow({mode:"open"})
  ) {
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = await (await fetch(src)).text()
    shadowRoot.append(...this.querySelectorAll("[shadowRoot]"))
    this.hasAttribute("replaceWith") && this.replaceWith(...shadowRoot.childNodes)
  }
})
load-file {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}
<load-file src="https://load-file.github.io/heart.svg">
    <style shadowRoot>
      path:nth-child(2n+2) {
        fill: GREEN; /* shadowDOM style does NOT style global DOM */
      }
    </style>
</load-file>
<load-file src="https://load-file.github.io/heart.svg"></load-file>
<load-file src="https://load-file.github.io/heart.svg">
    <style shadowRoot>
      path:nth-child(2n+2) {
        fill: RED; /* shadowDOM style does NOT style global DOM */
      }
    </style>
</load-file>





Make sue that the object is loaded
Query the desired child element from the Object's contentDocument
Use style.fill =

<object id="Soldier" type="image/svg+xml" data="ProvaSVG.svg" width="400" height="400"></object>

<script>
const elObject = document.querySelector("#Soldier");

elObject.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const elSVG = elObject.contentDocument.querySelector("svg");
  elSVG.querySelector("#COLOR1").style.fill = "green";
  elSVG.querySelector("#COLOR2").style.fill = "blue";
});
</script>



Thank you but it didn't work.

@SauroPasquini what did not work? Worked on my end. So the code is tested. Have you run a localhost server or you're trying to load files (the .svg) from file:///? Also, are the images on your server or you're trying to load them from another resource?

Your code simply try to change all my SVG file paths in red. But my SVG file is ocmposed by many,many paths, mainly without an ID, except one path with ID COLOR1 and another one with id COLOR2. I want to change them indepentnetly from all the other paths. And I'm trying this on file:/// not on a localhost.

@SauroPasquini well, it's a proof of concept, you can always adapt it to instead do: elSVG.querySelector("#COLOR1").style.fill = "green"; no? I've edited my answer.

Roko, thank you for the effort, but I tried and it tells me: Uncaught TypeError: elObject is null

Probably the fact that I'm not on localhost, that I'm trying this form file:/// matters ...

@SauroPasquini well, in that case I'd suggest you use a localhost / server. Itr's not hard to run one, specially not in VSCode, you simply click on the "Show Preview" icon in the tab's upper right corner.

@SauroPasquini <script> should go right before the closing </body> tag. Or otherwise add the defer attribute: <script defer src="">

I don't use VSCode, I use a text editor. I will check on how to set up a server ...

I placed the script in the head section.

@SauroPasquini than do as I said, place the script right before the closing </body> tag if you want JS to find that document.querySelector("#Soldier") - otherwise just add the defer attribute (if you want to leave it in HEAD)

Tried it, still same error: elObject.contentDocument is null

@SauroPasquini please run a local server... and use a better IDE than "a text editor". I told you, I've used the above code and worked perfectly fine. On a localhost. And having the svg file on that same localhost in root (same folder as the index.html file)

You're right! But I'm really "old school" and my editor of choice is a text editor. I'm not used to use an IDE. I will try. Thank you!

It is not clear from the question if you are running the HTML and SVG document from a web server. To make this work you need to run a web server. You cannot get access to the contentDocument if you just open the HTML file from the file system.
You must wait till the DOM is loaded before you can add an event listener to the object element. document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {}) will fire when the DOM is ready.
If the SVG ProvaSVG.svg has been cached by the browser it may not fire the load event. Therefor you can also test for the readystate of the contentDocument. If the readystate is complete, you know that the SVG has already been loaded.
Here is an example, where I change the color of the fill on the element with the ID COLOR1.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
      let svgObject = document.querySelector('object');

      if (svgObject.contentDocument.readystate == 'complete') {
        loadSVGHandler(svgObject);
      } else {
        svgObject.addEventListener('load', e => loadSVGHandler(e.target));
      }
    });

    function loadSVGHandler(svgObject) {
      let svgDocument = svgObject.contentDocument;

      let COLOR1 = svgDocument.getElementById('COLOR1');
      COLOR1.setAttribute('fill', 'Green');
    }

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <object width="400" height="400" data="ProvaSVG.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</body>

</html>


Thank you. In fact I'm running them from the file system and not from a web server.
